# How to get default values from a different table in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I made a Spring boot application in which I make CRUD operations on a table (Entity Model) (car) using JPA Hibernate and MYSQL

a car has columns : price - seatsNumber - .....

I want to make another Entity for default values for the car price and car seats numbers

so that If the user doesn't add a price or the seats number for a specific car the application
get the default values stored in the default values table.

how can I make that happen, what do I need please let me know as I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Column(name="price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '100.00'")
```

[More docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.x/reference/pdf/spring-data-jpa-reference.pdf)

Comment: this seems to set a default value without getting it from another table
I want to get the value from a different table where I store default values that's my homework instructions.

Comment: u can write custom logic in persistence layer for that, I dont think JPA will provide u something like that.